# JMockit - Can't bind mocked class to tested class

Tags: java, unit-testing, binding, mocking, jmockit

I have an application with 3 layers:
App <--> Graph <--> Couchbase

I'm trying to test the GraphConnector by mocking the couchbase layer and "replacing" it with a very basic in-memory graph implementation, using the same approach demonstrated in the JMockit [tutorial](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Introduction.html#mockups).

This is my test class (pardon the poor indentation, didn't get the hang of it yet):

```
public class GraphConnectorTest {
public static final class MockCouchbase extends MockUp<ICouchConnector> {
    private Map<String, CouchEntry> couch;

    @Mock
    public void $clinit() {
        couch = new HashMap<String, CouchEntry>();
    }

    @Mock
    public void put(CouchEntry entry) {
        couch.put(entry.getKey(), entry);
    }

    @Mock
    public CouchEntry get(String key) {
        return couch.get(key);
    }
}

GraphConnectorImpl graph = new GraphConnectorImpl();

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    new MockCouchbase();
}

@Test
public void testPost() throws Exception {
    GraphNode node = new GraphNode(GraphNodeType.DOMAIN, "alon.com");
    graph.post(node);
    GraphNode retNode = graph.getSingleNode(node.getValue(), node.getType());
    assertEquals(node.getValue(), retNode.getValue());
    assertEquals(node.getType(), retNode.getType());    
}
}
```

And here is my class under test:

```
public class GraphConnectorImpl implements IGraphConnector {

private static ICouchConnector couch = new CouchConnectorImpl();  // <-- Basic implementation which I don't want the test to execute

@Override
public void post(GraphNode node) {
    CouchEntry entry = new CouchEntry(node.getValue(), JsonDocument.create(node.getValue()));
    couch.put(entry);
}

@Override
public GraphNode getSingleNode(String nodeName, GraphNodeType nodeType) {
    return new GraphNode(nodeType, couch.get(nodeName).getKey());
}
}
```

For some reason, the class `MockCouchbase` that I created within the test class isn't automatically bound to the private field `ICouchConnector couch` of the tested class, as shown in the tutorial. Instead, the real implementation is called, which is obviously undesirable.
If I remove the reference to the real implementation, I just get a good ol' `NullPointerException`.
I tried playing with the `@Tested` and `@Injectable` annotations but to no avail.

Comment: Those example tests in the JMockit Tutorial apply `MockUp` on *classes*, not on an *interface*; huge difference. There is [documentation about mocking-up interfaces](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Faking.html#interfaces), though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving my own question.

The problem with the way I wrote the class under test was explicitly invoking the constructor of the real implementation. I'll be surprised if any mocking framework can "bypass" that.

Instead, I should've created a constructor that gets `ICouchConnector` as one of its arguments, e.g. use dependency injection properly.

```
public class GraphConnectorImpl implements IGraphConnector {
    private static ICouchConnector couch;

    public GraphConnectorImpl(ICouchConnector connector) {
        couch = connector;
    }
    // Rest of class...
}
```

JMockit will then attempt to find a constructor that corresponds to the fields annotated `@Tested` and `@Injectable` in the test class.

```
public class GraphConnectorTest {
    @Tested
    GraphConnectorImpl graph;

    @Injectable
    ICouchConnector couch;

    // Rest of class...
}
```

Comment: Actually, JMockit will mock the `CouchConnectorImpl` class just fine (with the code under test as is), provided the test uses `MockUp<CouchConnectorImpl>` or `@Mocked CouchConnectorImpl`.

Comment: It does mock the concrete class just fine, but whenever I call getMockInstance() (in order to declare Verifications() on the mocked class), it disables the mock's functionality and leaves me with a stub that complies to the interface but doesn't do anything (doesn't really call any method).

Comment: There's no use for `MockUp#getMockInstance()` in this case; and `Verifications` is part of another API, independent of and unrelated to `MockUp`.